# how to make vertical nav default state is collapsed?

Tags: javascript, vmware-clarity

Current implementation, default state of vertical Nav is always not-collapsed. How I can make the default state as collapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to set `clrVerticalNavCollapsed` to `true` on your vertical nav. So it would look like this:

```
<clr-vertical-nav [clrVerticalNavCollapsible]="true" [clrVerticalNavCollapsed]="true">
    ....
</clr-vertical-nav>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/collapsed-vertical-nav

Comment: just figured out that the example given in the docs is not correct. Thanks much!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you initially hide it and afterwards on a click event just show it with javascript?